# Parallelized code result in inflated memory usage in threads (RStudio deffect)

Tags: r, rstudio, glm, rparallel

### Overview:

my B object is a big matrix 100 000 * 5000 of 2 GB
my A object is smaller 1000 * 5000

```
analyse_with_glm <- function(Y) {
  cond1 = unlist(apply(B, 2, function(X) coef(summary(glm(Y~X)))[,4][2]))
  cond2 = unlist(apply(B, 2, function(X) coef(summary(glm(Y~X+cov2)))[,4][2]))
  cond3 = unlist(apply(B, 2, function(X) coef(summary(glm(Y~X+cov3)))[,4][2]))
  list(cond1, cond2, cond3)}

cl = makeCluster(nb_cpu, type = "FORK", outfile='outcluster.log')
res = parApply(cl, A, 2, analyse_with_glm)
```

Initially I have a single rsession process using 2.1GB of my mermoy.
After calling parApply function it I have nb_cpu threads of 4.5GB.

### Two questions:

- While B is only read, it could be shared from a single memory slot between threads. How to proceed ?
- Even though, why 4.5 GB per thread and not ~2.1GB ?

I use 'top' command to monitor thread and memory usage and this is not superficial usage that garbage collector can release. Threads crash for being out of memory. It run on a 128GB memory computer with 30 threads (nb_cpu = 30 in my code).

**NB:** I also tried contrary, using B (the big matrix) in parApply instead of A but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be partial as I still consider R behavior weird when it comes to parallelizing code.
If you run code from **RStudio**, parallel thread tend to be inflated by the size of **~/.rstudio/suspended-session-data/**

**So to avoid it, here is a dummy workaround.**
 1. Clean your environment
 2. Log-out
 3. Log-in
 4. Load your data
 5. Run parallel code

**INFO:**

- Rstudio 0.99.892
- R version 3.3.1

Comment: Have you tried to run your code from RGui? Is this issue related to RStudio IDE or to R in general? BTW. you should specify which versions of R and RStudio you are running and what the operating system is.